# javascript variable scope issue between two functions with callbacks

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation, scope

I want to concat two arrays. In the code below i am only getting txs_history array.

```
getFirstArray(function(txs) {
    getSecondArray(function(txs_history) {
        txs.concat(txs_history);
        res.send(txs_history);
    });    
});
```

From my knowledge i can guess that txs var can't be read inside getSecondArray and that's why it is only sent txs_history. I can't figure out how to solve this scope issue.

Regards,

Comment: If `txs` wouldn't be in scope, you'd get an exception that says so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`txs` is in scope, but `txs.concat()` returns a new array and leaves the original `txs` unmodified.  What you want is probably this:

```
getFirstArray(function(txs) {
    getSecondArray(function(txs_history) {
        var combined = txs.concat(txs_history);
        res.send(combined);
    });    
});
```